# How to prove the convergence of the serie $\sum \frac{\sin(3n\theta)}{\ln n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to show that $\sum \displaystyle\frac{\sin(3n\theta)}{\ln n}$ diverge or divergei know that $\displaystyle\sum \frac{1}{\ln n}$ diverge but how can i do this?

Comment: 1. What have you tried? 2. What is $\theta$? Do we know it?

Comment: You wrote "diverge  or diverge" - presumably you meant "converges or diverges"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Dirichlet's test, $\frac{1}{\ln n}$ is decreasing to $0$ and 
$\sum_{n=1}^{k} \sin n\theta$ is bounded. Thus the product converges.

Comment: Is it obvious that that sum is bounded? Certainly the terms are but that isn't sufficient. If theta is a rational multiple of pi, it's clear, but otherwise it seems like there's an additional argument.

Comment: No, a separate argument is needed to show that. There is a formula for such a sum, (easy to derive by considering the $\sum e^{in\theta}$), one then show that the sum is bounded.

Comment: Unless theta is small, you wouldn't have convergence of that sum, either, would you?

Comment: Even for small theta the sum will diverge.

Comment: If theta is (say) -10 the sum converges by the geometric series test, but I'll admit I didn't think my comment all the way through.